# SQL ORDER BY before GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

This question has been asked and answered many times before, but my case is a bit different.

Say I have this data:

```
------------------------------
| id       | date            |
------------------------------
| 1        | 2016-07-15      |
| 1        | 2016-07-16      |
| 2        | 2016-07-24      |
| 2        | 2016-07-25      |
| 1        | 2016-07-29      |
| 1        | 2016-07-30      |
------------------------------
```

I want to first order by the `date` column, and then group by the `id` column and take the `max(date)` for each `id`.

So I would get this

```
------------------------------
| id       | max(date)       |
------------------------------
| 1        | 2016-07-16      |
| 2        | 2016-07-25      |
| 1        | 2016-07-30      |
------------------------------
```

Notice that `id=1` appears twice, because the order by caused 2 separate "groups" of `id=1`, with a group of `id=2` in between them.

What I mean is that I want the `group by` function to only group together rows of the same value that are placed next to each other by the `order by` clause.

How can I do that?

Comment: What's the max date difference allowed so that the difference makes those dates put into a single group?

Comment: @1000111 there is no "difference limit". The point is that I want to group together only rows of the same `id` that were placed next to each other by the `order by` clause

Comment: Don't you have any primary key in your table?

Comment: Your data violates [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) ("no top-to-bottom ordering to the rows"), the most basic requirement of the relational model on which SQL is based. I guess this makes querying your data with SQL more difficult than it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use variable here.

```
select id, `date`
from (
    select 
        id, 
        `date`, 
        @rowno := case when @grp = id then @rowno + 1 else 0 end as rowno,
        @grp := id
    from (
        select *
        from yourtable
        order by `date` desc
    ) t1
    cross join (select @grp := null, @rowno = 0) t2
) main
where main.rowno = 0
order by `date`;
```

the inner query will organize the record like this,

```
---------------------------------------------
| id       | date            | rowno | @grp |
---------------------------------------------
| 1        | 2016-07-30      | 0     | 1    |
| 1        | 2016-07-29      | 1     | 1    |
| 2        | 2016-07-25      | 0     | 2    |
| 2        | 2016-07-24      | 1     | 2    |
| 1        | 2016-07-16      | 0     | 1    |
| 1        | 2016-07-15      | 1     | 1    |
---------------------------------------------
```

then a where clause `rowno = 0` will get what you want.

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7440a1/1)

Comment: This returns the first date instead of the last date per id.

Comment: This seems quite clever, is the order guaranteed without an `ORDER BY` in `main`?

Comment: @P.Salmon I've tested it, also you can run this query in sqlfiddle, but it seems down.

Comment: @mendosi Without `order by`, the order will not be guaranteed. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. You have order by in subquery `t1` which guarantees the order at that point, but AFAIK the order is not guaranteed in subquery `main`, and that is the part of your statement that *absolutely depends* upon correct order. Correct me if I'm wrong, just trying to follow how this works.

Comment: @mendosi Ad you know, except for `limit`, `order by` should be the last operation in one mysql execution, in `t1`, the ordered record will be read by `main`'s select clause one by one, then this `rowno` will be meaningful, or this will get unpredictable results. Anyway, you can run this query and test it. If I'am wrong, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ for a bit more details.